react native flatlist component let some item occupy the rest， how to do it
react native flatlist component let some item occupy the rest， how to do it？
make some item take the rest of screen
i tried to set the item style property “flex: 1”, but doesn't work, Has anyone encountered the same need
I want to achieve

<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          ref={current}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparatorComponent}
          style={{ paddingLeft: 8, paddingRight: 8 }}
          stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}
          data={[
            { component: <QA />, key: 'qa' },
            { component: <Tab />, key: 'tab' },
            {} //  here, item need to taked the rest
            ...list,
          ]}
          renderItem={({ item }) => item.component || <ActivityItem />}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
          onEndReached={endReachedHandler}
          refreshing={refreshing}
          onRefresh={refreshHandler}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${index}-${item.key ?? ''}`}
        />
        <View style={{ padding: 8, paddingBottom: 6 }}>
          <Button
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate({
                routeName: 'Edit',
                params: {},
              })
            }}
          >
            create
          </Button>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>


